# PHP mail and Lines should not be larger than 70 characters

Tags: php

I can't understand this line from the official documentation of mail function in PHP:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

> Each line should be separated with a LF (\n). Lines should not be
>   larger than 70 characters.

Even more, in their example they recommens to do something like this:

```
// The message
$message = "Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3";

// In case any of our lines are larger than 70 characters, we should use wordwrap()
$message = wordwrap($message, 70);
```

Why is that? and **what happens with URLs for example**? they are frequently much larger than 70 characters
What are the problems we could have if we don't do it?

Thanks!

Comment: You should use a mailer library like Swiftmailer, PHPMailer or Zend_Mail. They're much more robust than the simple `mail()` and work around many quirks that otherwise you'd have to face.

Comment: yes, I'm not planning to use mail, but I like to learn these weird things :)

Comment: the last (optional) parameter (defaults to false) indicates whether it should wrap excessively long words, or leave them on a single line

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several ways to overcome the 70 char limit, using [`quoted_printable_encode`](http://www.php.net/quoted_printable_encode) for instance, or familiar `base64_encode`. However, there are not that many clients left that cannot deal with long lines, although it is of course best to adhere to it if you are able.

Comment: so the 70 chars limit is deprecated? what could happen if I don't break the lines?

Comment: Not deprecated, just voilated violently everywhere so applications tend to be robust enough now. Not breaking lines could result in non-delivery, but a public secret is that as long as lines are shorter then around 900 chars or so, nothing bad tends to happen.