# Max line length in mail

Tags: php, email

Why is the [php documentation of mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) saying

> Lines should not be larger than 70 characters.

(under the part: parameter message)?

Is there an RFC specifying the line length of mails?

This question: 
[PHP mail and Lines should not be larger than 70 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9054708/php-mail-and-lines-should-not-be-larger-than-70-characters) says

> there are not that many clients left that cannot deal with long lines

So is it just bad build clients/servers that do bad stuff to too long lines,
and 70 is a tested value that works well enough, or is there an RFC or something that
says that mail-applications need to handle 70 char long lines?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The *Internet Message Format* RFC the latest of which is [5322](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322.txt)

> 2.1.1. Line Length Limits
>
> There are two limits that this standard places on the number of
>   characters in a line. Each line of characters MUST be no more than 998
>   characters, and SHOULD be no more than 78 characters, excluding the
>   CRLF.
>
> ...
>
> The more conservative 78 character recommendation is to accommodate
>   the many implementations of user interfaces that display these
>   messages which may truncate, or disastrously wrap, the display of more
>   than 78 characters per line, in spite of the fact that such
>   implementations are non-conformant to the intent of this specification
>   (and that of [RFC2821] if they actually cause information to be lost).
>   Again, even though this limitation is put on  messages, it is
>   encumbant upon implementations which display messages

(The MIME RFC also specifies a max of 76 characters)

Comment: Damn, this took me a whole day to debug. I was composing an email from a form that is 4 pages. The emails just stopped sending at some point and I could not figure out why. To remedy this, I threw in a few line breaks `$message .= "\r\n";` in and bam! Started working again. Note: The line breaks must be surrounded by double quotes, not single quotes.